# How to get parent Information from child object with TYPO3 extbase

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a classical course and dates relation (one course has many dates). The next courses shall be listed on a page. I loaded all dates with the normal findAll() method with sorting by startDate. Now i need the parent course information in order to show course details.

In the date controller i have

```
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ITServicePN\ItspnKurse\Domain\Model\Kurse>
 */
protected $kurse = NULL;

/**
 * Returns the Courses
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ITServicePN\ItspnKurse\Domain\Model\Kurse> $kurse
 */
public function getKurse() {
    return $this->kurse;
}
```

This returns me the course when using f:debug {date.kurse}:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items) ... => ITServicePN\ItspnKurse\Domain\Model\Kurseprototypepersistent entity (uid=8, pid=51)
      title => 'The name of the course' ...
```

But when i try to access {date.kurse.title} i got a TYPO3 exception:

```
#1: PHP Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /var/www/vhosts/it-service-pn.de/cetba/typo3_src-6.2.3/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/ObjectStorage.php line 174
```

What to do, to get the parents object information properly with extbase and fluid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Model, `kurse` is an ObjectStorage. That means when accessing `date.kurse`in fluid you will get an Array back.
You can iterate over that array in fluid with the [for-Viewhelper](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/For.html)

```
<f:for each="{date.kurse}" as="kurs">
    Kurs: {kurs.title}
</f:for>
```

You can also print the index of the iteration to get a numbered list of kurses.

```
<f:for each="{date.kurse}" as="kurs" iteration="i">
    {i.cycle}. Kurs: {kurs.title}
</f:for>
```